# solution for wrapping a pointer in a std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I need to have `int**` to pass to API function call written in C. Based on the description of the API, it uses `malloc` to allocate memory, and it requires the user to free the memory after it is returned.

How to create a `std::unique_ptr<int*>` ? If I have one, does `.get()` function return a `int**`. I was thinking if I could wrap my pointer in a `unique_ptr` and make sure it will be freed when out of scope. I am not sure if the following implementation ensures that memory is freed after allocation? Is there a better way of achieving this?

```
int ** get_double_ptr()
{
    int ** ids;
    return ids;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    std::unique_ptr<int*> i_ptr(get_double_ptr());

    int ** idx = i_ptr.get();
    // allocate ids using malloc ....

}
```

The C function is declared as below:

```
int MeshToNodal(int *ne, int *nn, int *eptr, int *eind, int *numflag,
int **xadj, int **adjncy)
```

Comment: @tilz0R: The user is asking about interfacing with C code. That involves knowing about C code.

Comment: I am calling a API that is written in C from a c++ code

Comment: The pointer you gave `unique_ptr` to `delete` later is not the pointer that was allocated. Also using `delete` when you were supposed to use `free` is not correct.

Comment: Could you add the declaration of the `C` function you are trying to call? Is it a `int**` because it is going to allocate an array of `int` for you, or is int a `int**` because it is going to use an array of pointer you allocated before?

Comment: Your question is contradicted: if you pass array, then memory already allocated, if memory is allocated inside C call, then you pass pointer, not array. You need to be more clear.

Comment: Still the tag [tag:c] should be appropriate when the question is about *interfacing* with C code. Don't be too quick removing tags.